# listagg query result distinct values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table like this

```
+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| Customer_ref(varchar2(40)) | Event_source-varchar2(40)) |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| ctx10000012                | 12474748,1247574,1247674   |
| ctx10000013                | 12474748,12474749,12474750 |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

```
SELECT LISTAGG(EVENT_SOURCE, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY EVENT_SOURCE) from 
            ( select distinct  customer_ref, EVENT_SOURCE from CUSTEVENTSOURCE where   customer_ref = Acc.Customer_ref AND END_DTM IS NULL)
```

the output of the table should be like

```
+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| Customer_ref(varchar2(40)) | Event_source-varchar2(40)) |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| ctx10000012                | 12474748,1247574,1247674   |
| ctx10000013                | 12474748 - 12474750        |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

How can  i do this, in the single select query (with out using with as table select ()).Because I am using this select query inside the cursor.

your help is appreciated.

Comment: `single select query (with out using with as table select ()).Because I am using this select query inside the cursor.` What does it mean can u put sample code which is not working?

Comment: @Pratik-With in the single select query,I just want to give the output whether the eventsoucre is in sequence or not.If sequence need to give '-'as separator.

Comment: please guys... please help me in solving this problem..I need ur help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in function to help you here. So write a PL/SQL function called ranges_string (or whatever name you like) yourself, converting a string from '1,2,3,5,7,8,9' to '1-3,5,7-9' (or however you need it) and then call it in your select statement:

```
select ranges_string( listagg(event_source, ', ') within group(order by event_source) )
from
(
  select distinct customer_ref, event_source from custeventsource
  where customer_ref = acc.customer_ref and end_dtm is null
);
```

EDIT: Here is a function to convert to ranges (convert '1,2,3,6,7,8,10,12,13,14' to '1-3,6-8,10,12-14' for instance). I haven't spent much time on it, so it is certainly not great, so feel free to change it :-)

```
create or replace function convert_ranges(vi_numbers varchar2) return varchar2 is
  type table_of_integer is table of integer index by binary_integer;
  v_numbers table_of_integer;
  v_ranges varchar2(4000);
  v_pos integer;
  v_count integer;
begin
  -- Tokenize
  select regexp_substr(vi_numbers, '[^,]+', 1, level) as num
  bulk collect into v_numbers
  from dual
  connect by regexp_substr(vi_numbers, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;

  -- Collect
  v_ranges := v_numbers(1);
  v_pos := 2;
  while v_pos <= v_numbers.count loop
    v_count := 0; 
    while v_pos <= v_numbers.count and v_numbers(v_pos) = v_numbers(v_pos-1) + 1 loop
      v_count := v_count + 1;
      v_pos := v_pos + 1;
    end loop;
    if v_count > 0 then
      v_ranges := v_ranges || '-' || v_numbers(v_pos-1);
    end if;
    if v_pos <= v_numbers.count then
      v_ranges := v_ranges || ',';
      v_ranges := v_ranges || v_numbers(v_pos);
      v_pos := v_pos + 1;
    end if;
  end loop;

  return v_ranges;
end convert_ranges;
```

Comment: :can you please help me in writing the ranges_string function because as i am new to sql.

Comment: I have added a function doing more or less what you need. Hope this helps. (BTW: I am sure you would have got immediate help, if you had posted a new request rather than adding a comment in an already solved one. There are certainly many who would have provided such a function quickly, had they only seen your request.)